# Can you containerize different django applications belonging to a single project in different docker containers?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-templates

So basically, I have three different modules or apps in a single django project - These are registration application (registers the user), login application (login), status application (retrieves the data and displays the currently online users). I use redirects to redirect from one template to another such that the registration page will redirect to the login html page and so on. I have kept all the html files in a template folder. I have a common project for all these applications. I want to containerize each of these applications in to a single container, such that I would have three different containers but I am having troubles in understanding how the redirects would work? As these applications are interacting with each other, how would I be doing this? I would implement the databae on AWS or GCloud.

Comment: If the three components share the code base, you can launch three (or more) containers from the same image with different commands.  You probably want all three to be behind some sort of load balancer or proxy so they can share a host name and route on URL path, but that setup depends heavily on where you're deploying it.

Comment: You can use 2 new lines in a row  to create a paragraph. That allows you to make you question more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it, I hope I can help.
You can do this with docker-compose in the following way.
Create 3 containers with the same image, same network and different names. Assign a separate port to each container for example use `8000, 8001` and `8002`.
Now use a webserver for redirect pages.
run a Nginx container and placing different upstream for different pages.
Nginx listen port 80 and then redirect each page to their container.

```
    upstream register_domain_com {
    server 1.2.3.4:8000;
}

    upstream login_domain_com {
    server 1.2.3.4:8001;
}

.
.
.
```